# How to get current yaw and pitch axis (vector) of a camera given mlab.view() and mlab.roll() in mayavi?

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, visualization, mayavi

I'm doing some visualization using mayavi and I'm trying to calculate the yaw and pitch's rotation axis from mlab.view() and mlab.roll(). I'm not sure how mlab.roll() is defined and is it possible to get current view's up-down, right-left directions?

[Camera handling functions](http://github.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_camera.html?highlight=roll)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mlab.view() called with no arguments returns the current view, the azimuth is the yaw and the elevation is the pitch.